# Appropriate way to read inputs of a program called by a script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have two files, commands.txt and mk.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
./program < commands.txt
```

Where commands.txt contains the list of inputs of program, for example:

```
#c1
3
3
fileName
```

This solution it's not good at all, because program ends with EOF Exception, and i'm sure that's a better way to do this. So, what's your suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to run `program` for each line of input OR want to pass all the inputs at once?

Comment: Depends how the program is written. Could you provide some info on the program please ?

Comment: I want to give each input to program in an order, like my example.

Comment: The program is written in this way: it requires some inputs from command line, the first is a command that starts with #, two numbers and a string that represents the output file. Does it really matter?

Comment: Why do you think there is a better way? This is basically how you do it. The EOF error indicates that the program expects more input than you are providing, though (or perhaps it is reading more than you think at an earlier point -- if it reads two lines when you expect it to only take one, that would put things out of whack).

Comment: Yes, but i think there's a way to not create an auxiliar file like commands.txt and put the commands in an array or something like that. Am i wrong?

Comment: @anubhava I want to execute program once, and then give some ordered arguments.

Comment: ok you mean this: `./program $(<commands.txt)`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, just like my example. It works, but i don't want to create a file to put the inputs in each line, like commands.txt. That's my point. Anyway, thank you for trying to help me. :)

Comment: ok in that case you can use heredoc and avoid file creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making explicit the solution given by anubhava in comments:

```
#!/bin/bash
./program << EOF
#c1
3
3
fileName
EOF
```